# FLUTTER: I had this problem after I updated to a newer version, How can I fix it

Tags: android, windows, flutter

*****Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
>   Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.
>        Required by:
>            project :app
>   Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.
>   Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'whttp://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.pom'.
>   Connection reset
>   Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.
>   Could not get resource 'whttp://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'whttp://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.pom'.
>   Connection reset
>   Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.
>   Could not get resource 'whttp://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'whttp://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.pom'.
>   Connection reset
>   Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.
>        Required by:
>            project :app
>   Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.
>   Could not get resource 'whttp://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c/x86_debug-1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'whttp://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c/x86_debug-1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.pom'.
>   Connection reset
>   Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.
>   Could not get resource 'whttp://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c/x86_debug-1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'whttp://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c/x86_debug-1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.pom'.
>   Connection reset
>   Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.
>   Could not get resource 'whttp://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c/x86_debug-1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'whttp://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c/x86_debug-1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.pom'.
>   Connection reset
>   Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.
>        Required by:
>            project :app
>   Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.
>   Could not get resource 'whttp://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'whttp://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.pom'.
>   Connection reset
>   Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.
>   Could not get resource 'whttp://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'whttp://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.pom'.
>   Connection reset
>   Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.
>   Could not get resource 'whttp://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'whttp://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.pom'.
>   Connection reset
>   * Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>   * Get more help at whttps://help.gradle.org
>   BUILD FAILED in 1m 55s
>   Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
>   Exited (sigterm)*****

****gotta put W infront of the http:// to get this question posted

Comment: Whats the output of `flutter doctor -v` and maybe try running `flutter clean`.

Comment: have tried it but still not working

Answer (score 1):

You should see what new version of Flutter needs Gridel.
So you better create a new project with a new version of Flutter then see what changes have been made to your project in the **build.gradle** , **gradle-wrapper.properties** , **gradle.properties** files.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem.

Sometimes, when compiling in VS Code, the actual errors are not being shown. 
So, I opened Android Studio and tried to compile the project again.

Then, it gave me some actual errors that could be fixed. I fixed the errors and went back to VS Code, where it started to compile as expected.